# Path/Url helpers not being generated for resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have create a routing rule in my `routes.rb` file:

```
namespace :pricing do
  resources :discounts do
  end
end
```

However, when I list all my URLs, there are no helpers for POST/PUT/DELETE methods, only for GET methods.

[image]

The controller has all necessary methods (`index, new, create, edit, update, destroy`). The only "difference" compared to other parts of my application is that `Pricing::Discount` is not a model, but rather a viewmodel, because the information come from a 3rd party web API (compared to traditional database models).

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the same url helper name just the different methods, e.g., below the first one is using `get` method

```
= link_to 'Pricing Discount', pricing_discount_path(@discount)
```

but, the second one is using `put`

```
= link_to 'Pricing Discount', pricing_discount_path(@discount), method: 'put'
```

Both of them use same url helper, i.e., `pricing_discount_path(@discount)`, but it's the methods that maps them to their respective actions.

Hope that helps!